# Why does for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i) return "'<' signed/unsigned mismatch"?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
```

and i get the following error:'<': signed/unsigned mismatch

THE_WORD was initialized like this:

```
const string THE_WORD;
```

I am trying to make a "hangman" program (learning cpp on my own right now) and this is part of a for loop that iterates through the word the player is supposed to guess and changes the character in place from an asterisk to the guessed letter.

Let me know if I need to post more code for my question to be answered.

Comment: The above link deals with `size()` instead of `length()` but is the exact same issue.

Comment: A string length cannot be negative (think about it), which is why the `std::string::length()` returns an **unsigned** quantity.

Comment: ``size_t uint32_t uint8_t`` etc. are preferable to use over "naked" int and "unsigned int" etc. types, as the sizes of naked types are platform specific. If for example you change your int now to an unsigned int and switch your compile to x64, you will run into the next problem, as on 64 bit compiles size_t is 8 bytes long, while unsigned int is still 4 bytes long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the type returned by `length()` call is size_t which is usually a `typedef` of `unsigned int`. That's why it is signed/unsigned mismatch between signed integer which is `int` and `size_t` type which is the value returned by `std::string::length()`.

To make it correct consider to change type of your `i` variable to `size_t` or any other unsigned type, but it is better to make types identical (`size_t` and `size_t`):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm on chapter 4 of this book and it hasn't mentioned a "size_t" yet! Good to know for the future!